# Deleting an instance of a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, class, object, instances

I have a JavaScript Object called box_brick:

```
function box_brick( attribute1, attribute2, etc )
{
    this.attribute_1 = attribute1;
    this.attribute_2 = attribute2;
    this.attribute_etc = etc;

    box_brick.instances.push(this);
}
```

I create new box_bricks by declaring them:

```
var box_62 = new box_brick('new attribute 1', 'new attribute 2', 'etc');
```

This works well for my application, and gives me **box_brick.instances**:

[image]

The way my code is set up, each time a new box is created, I have both the instance in **box_brick.instances**, as well as a standalone object, which I can then call directly to get information from. For example, to get **brick_60**'s color, I can just invoke **brick_60.box_color**, and in this case I would receive '#ff008c'.

(These may be one and the same -- I am still a little unclear on the difference between objects, instances, classes, and so on, for which I apologize)

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to *delete* one of these box_bricks from the box_brick.instances -- for example, if I wanted to delete **brick_60**, so that it's not longer in box_brick.instances, I'm not sure how I would go about doing it.

I've tried doing brick_60.delete, delete(brick_60); and many other things, but am fully stumped.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `.filter`? How about `.splice`?

Comment: How can ` box_brick.instances.push(this);` even work if its invalid code?

Comment: @Robert Rocha Presumably he has initialized `box_brick.instances` to `[]` somewhere.

Comment: Hi Chris, if you feel your question has been answered, please don't forget to mark some answers as "helpful" using the arrows, and one of them as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate so we can further help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6, use a **`Set`**.

ES6 sets are "bags" of things which are there or not. Unlike an array, which you have to iterate over to find something, with sets, you can just add and delete items directly. They are pre-indexed by their contents, as it were.

```
// constructor
function box_brick( attribute1, attribute2, etc )
{
    ...
    box_brick.instances.add(this);
                        ^^^^^^^^^      // add to set
}

// initialize set
box_brick.instances = new Set();

// create a new instance
box_brick_instance = new box_brick(...);

// remove it from the set
box_brick.instances.delete(box_brick_instance);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    // delete from set
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an array, so you can do either `delete box_brick.instances[0]` or `box_brick.instances.splice(position, 1)`.

However, because you're using an array, you'd have to use indexof() to find the array index of the box_ID to be able to delete the instance.

Let's try using an object instead, with its scope outside of the function constructor:

```
// use a dictionary object to hold references to your objects:
var boxes = Object.create(null);

function box_brick(attribute1, attribute2, etc ) {

    this.attribute_1 = attribute1;
    this.attribute_2 = attribute2;
    this.attribute_etc = etc;

    var id = $.now().toString(); // use jQuery to create a unique ID from the UTC timestamp
    boxes[id] = this; // easier to use a unique id to augment object
}
```

Now it's easy to remove box instances:

```
function deleteBox(id) {
    if (boxes[id]) delete boxes[id];
}
```

Comment: Is there some particular reason `+new Date()` would not work and you recommend using jQuery? Also, you don't need to check for membership before deleting.

Comment: Time is not unique enought. It's not a problem to get the same time for 2 different function calls.

Comment: @torazaburo you don't need to check it.

Comment: @zerkms According to jQuery docs, "The `$.now()` method is a shorthand for the number returned by the expression `(new Date).getTime()`.", so it's exactly the same.

Comment: I'm also confused by how the user is ever supposed to know which ID to call `deleteBox` with, since it's never exposed to the outside world...

Comment: @torazaburo "so it's exactly the same" --- and? It's still just a ms resolution, which is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays are not indexed in any specific way, the only way to do this will be by iterating through to find the brick you want. I might recommend changing your data structure to be an object instead of an array, but following is a solution to get what you have working.

Below is a `deleteID` function that will iterate through and delete an an element with a specific id. In the following example, we remove the brick with `id` of `"brick_2"`.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var bricks = [];
bricks.push({box_id: "brick_1"});
bricks.push({box_id: "brick_2"});
bricks.push({box_id: "brick_3"});

function deleteID(id) {
    for (brick in bricks) {
        if (bricks[brick].box_id === id) bricks.splice(brick, 1);
    }
}

deleteID("brick_2");
document.getElementById("output").textContent = JSON.stringify(bricks);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/fef3o6vv/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the assistance -- I've found that the .splice() function, suggested by elclanrs and Data, did exactly what I was hoping for. I'm using the following code and it works great:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < box_brick.instances.length; i++ )
{

    if ( box_brick.instances[i].box_id == box_to_delete )
    {
        box_brick.instances.splice(i, 1);
    }

}
```

Although this doesn't remove the standalone var / Object of a box (so in the console, I can still type **brick_55.attribute** and get a value), I've decided to just allow those variables to stay in memory, and use **box_brick.instances** as my sort of "master list" of all the *actual* boxes that are relevant to the application, disregarding the standalone var versions (which contain the same redundant information).

Thank you all so much! I sunk many, many hours into this before turning to StackOverflow, and your guys' guidance was just what I needed.

Comment: I'm very glad you ended up getting this resolved, but I can't help but note that this answer is almost exactly the same as the answer I posted a week ago...